# Non-admin role can see CiviCRM links in profile, no privileges selected

Tags: drupal

I am building a new website but migrated the entire CiviCRM database, files and settings from the old site. Authenticated users and other roles are able to see fields from the CiviCRM that pertain to them as well as a link to edit them. There are no CiviCRM privileges selected so I feel like there may be some custom programming at work here.

What I know:

- No privileges are selected for role in Drupal
- Links go to tabs they can edit from their Drupal profile (see screenshots)
- At least some of these fields are custom in the CiviCRM

Screenshots
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add visibility to specific roles on Drupal profile so they can contribute information when editing their profile.

The custom fields in Administer > Custom Data and Screens > Profiles has a setting: view/edit Drupal User Account. Select or deselect as desired.

[image]